# JSF fileUpload to server with pathname in database

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I have code working which uploads a file to my database.
I would like to now store the filename in my database while storing the file content in a local folder.
My postgresql database already works.
I'm using the Seam 2 framework.

My html page:

```
<s:fileUpload data="#{filterHome.content}"
rendered="#{filterHome.uploadNewData}"
contentType="text/xml" required="true" >
</s:fileUpload>
```

My backing bean:

```
public byte[] getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(byte[] content) {
    this.content = content;
}
```

---

```
@Override
public String persist() {
/....
filter.setContent(content);
```

---

```
public String downloadFilter(){
/.....
for (int i = 0 ; i < getDefinedInstance().getContent().length; i++){
                response.getOutputStream().write(getDefinedInstance().getContent()[i]);
            }
```

Comment: You forget to post an actual problem description. All you posted is what you want to achieve and some snippets of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to capture original filename (which is uploaded from client). use fileName attribute for s:fileUpload.

```
<s:fileUpload data="#{filterHome.content}" rendered="#{filterHome.uploadNewData}" contentType="text/xml" required="true" fileName="#{filterHome.fileName}" >
```

also add fileName property (with getter and setter) to backing bean.